# Div keeps moving down the page when opened on different computers

Tags: css, html, position, css-position

Okay so this is quite hard to explain but basically I position the title div perfectly so that it is centered in the header div.

It remains in this position on some computers.

However, on other computers it jumps further down the page - even with the same positioning attributes. (This is tested on the same web browser.)

I have tried with absolute, relative etc. positioning, still no luck!

**Note: This div contains text.**

CSS:

```
#header {
    position:relative;
    height:170px;
    background-color: #30A7BF;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 1px;
}

#title {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: 315px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by computers? different browsers? different screen resolution?

Comment: @Nikitas The same browser (IE) but yes the screens are of different resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi is difficult to understand exactly your issue but I can give you a few tips to have a nice center `vertical` and `horizontal`:

- For horizontal alignment you can use `display:inline-block` if you want all the div centered:

  ```
  #header {
   text-align:center;
  }
  #title {
   display:inline-block;
  }
  ```
- For vertical align use `line-height` equal to the total `height`

  ```
  #header {
   line-height:170px;
  }
  ```

  <sub>This only work for one line text if you want another option tell me</sub>

And the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/8JLzy/7/

**Edit**

- To work with a text of more than one line you can do this : First your html add a wrapper inside `#title`:

  ```
  <div id="header">
    <div id="title">
      <div class="center">Your Title</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

  And on the CSS work with `display` property:

  ```
  #title {
     display:table;
     height:100%;
     margin:auto; /*Make the horizontal*/
  }
  #title .center {
     display:table-cell;
     vertical-align:middle;/*Make the Vertical*/
  }
  ```

  New demo **http://jsfiddle.net/8JLzy/16/**

Comment: There is two lines of text within this div. It is the vertical align that is relevant. Basically the issue is that the div is positioned fine on one computer but then on another it will move down the page more.

Answer (score 0):

use line-height, not position:relative

```
#header {
    /*position:relative;*/
    height:170px;
    background-color: #30A7BF;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 1px;
    font-size:1em;

}

#title {
    line-height:0.5em; /* for example, or instead use padding-top: */
    padding-left: 315px;

}
```

Comment: this doesn't work because there are two separate paragraphs in the div and this attribute just alters the space between them.

Comment: Then simply use padding-top instead of line-height, but maybe not to use position: for such a trivial task